# Restart KSQL-Server when some queries are running

Tags: ksqldb

I try to find some document about it, that when some queries are running and KSQL-Server restarts. What will happened?

Does it perform similar to Kafka-Streams, so the consumer offset is not committed and at-least-once is guaranteed?

I can observe that the queries stored in the command topic, and queries are executed when ksql-server restarts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to find some document about it, that when some queries are running and KSQL-Server restarts. What will happened?

If you only have a single KSQL server, then stopping that server will of course stop all the queries. Once the server is running again, all queries will continue from the points they stopped processing. No data is lost.

If you have multiple KSQL servers running, then stopping one (or some) of them will cause the remaining servers to take over any query processing tasks from the stopped servers. Once the stopped servers have been restarted the query processing workload will be shared again across all servers.

> Does it perform similar to Kafka-Streams, so the consumer offset is not committed and at-least-once is guaranteed?

Yes.

But (even better): Whether the processing guarantees are *at-least-once* or *exactly-once* depends solely on the KSQL server's *configuration*. It does of course not depend on whether or when the server is being restarted, crashes, etc.

Comment: does it apply also to the queries created from the CLI or the KSQL REST API?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't matter through which way a query was created.